# Optimal way to obtain substrings?

Tags: java, substring

Is there a more optimal way to obtain subtrings which are separated by ',' and ended by '.' than this way?

```
if (paramsText != null)
   {
       while (paramsText.contains(","))
         {
            params.add(paramsText.substring(0, paramsText.indexOf(",")));
            paramsText = paramsText.substring(
                    paramsText.indexOf(",") + 1, paramsText.length());
         }

         params.add(paramsText);
   }
```

Comment: you don't have a `"."` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would suit you:

```
String str = "There is, a more optimal, way to obtain. subtrings which,"
           + "are separated by, and ended by. than this way.";

String[] substrings = str.split("\\s*[.,]\\s*");
for (String substr : substrings)
    System.out.println("\"" + substr + "\"");
```

**Output:**

```
"There is"
"a more optimal"
"way to obtain"
"subtrings which"
"are separated by"
"and ended by"
"than this way"
```

Comment: After doing `String[] substrings = str.split("\\s*[.,]\\s*");
` I need to have `substrings` as a List<String>, hence I will have to cycle through the Array, will the total result be more Optimal than my original code? BTW, I am asking this because this function will translate from Spanish to English or vice-versa the contents of a web-page, Thanks

Comment: If you need a list interface to an array, you can do `Arrays.asList(substrings)`, but I wouldn't worry too much of preformance in this little snippet of code unless it turns out to be a bottleneck... I mean, if you're aiming to push it through a translator, I bet the bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, this should increase the performance at least a little bit ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since you aren't actually checking for a "." you can do this:

```
String[] params = paramsText.split(",");
```

Comment: Works, however I need to call a function later on with params as a List<String>, I will have to cycle through the Array to obtain an equivalent List right?

Comment: @camiloqp List<String> l = Arrays.asList(<your array here>);